# Check if a column of strings from one dataframe contains a substring from a column in another dataframe, and output its mapped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes. The first dataframe has certain **strings**

```
df_string = pd.DataFrame({'idx':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'string':['xx01122txt01', 'bea2125', 'spddoc0010', 'bon007', 'xx001122xls04', 'spdxls1122', 'bea1234', 'bon1234', 'xy02125doc00', 'irnppt1260']})
```

And the other three dataframes have **substrings** with some sort of mapping

```
df_name = pd.DataFrame({'code':['bon', 'bea', 'spd'],
                   'name':['james bond', 'mr bean', 'spider man']})
df_type = pd.DataFrame({'code':['doc', 'txt', 'xls'],
                   'type':['document', 'text', 'excel']})
df_desc = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1122', '1234', '2990', '2125'],
                   'desc':['facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'snapchat']})
```

What I'm trying to do is, look for the **substrings** in the **strings** column and create a new dataframe with the mapped data. It needs to look something like this

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'string': ['xx01122txt01', 'bea2125', 'spddoc0010', 'bon007', 'xx001122xls04', 'spdxls1122', 'bea1234', 'bon1234', 'xy02125doc00', 'irnppt1260'],
                   'desc': ['facebook', 'snapchat', '-', '-', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'twitter', 'snapchat', '-'],
                   'type': ['text', '-', 'document', '-', 'excel', 'excel', '-', '-', 'document', '-'],
                   'name': ['-', 'mr bean', 'spider man', 'james bond', '-', 'spider man', 'mr bean', 'james bond', '-', '-'
]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.extract` to extract the matched string in `string` column then `map` it to other column of `df_name`, `df_desc`

```py
df_string['desc'] = df_string['string'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(df_desc['id'])+')')[0].map(df_desc.set_index('id')['desc'])
df_string['type'] = df_string['string'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(df_type['code'])+')')[0].map(df_type.set_index('code')['type'])
df_string['name'] = df_string['string'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(df_name['code'])+')')[0].map(df_name.set_index('code')['name'])
```

```
print(df_string)


   idx         string      desc      type        name
0    1   xx01122txt01  facebook      text         NaN
1    2        bea2125  snapchat       NaN     mr bean
2    3     spddoc0010       NaN  document  spider man
3    4         bon007       NaN       NaN  james bond
4    5  xx001122xls04  facebook     excel         NaN
5    6     spdxls1122  facebook     excel  spider man
6    7        bea1234   twitter       NaN     mr bean
7    8        bon1234   twitter       NaN  james bond
8    9   xy02125doc00  snapchat  document         NaN
9   10     irnppt1260       NaN       NaN         NaN
```

```
print(df_string.fillna('-'))

   idx         string      desc      type        name
0    1   xx01122txt01  facebook      text           -
1    2        bea2125  snapchat         -     mr bean
2    3     spddoc0010         -  document  spider man
3    4         bon007         -         -  james bond
4    5  xx001122xls04  facebook     excel           -
5    6     spdxls1122  facebook     excel  spider man
6    7        bea1234   twitter         -     mr bean
7    8        bon1234   twitter         -  james bond
8    9   xy02125doc00  snapchat  document           -
9   10     irnppt1260         -         -           -
```